# Typescript module resolution fails despite "main" property set in package.json

Tags: reactjs, typescript, module

Within below folder structure, I would like to import my component into `App.tsx` this way:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
```

Typescript throws an error, despite my `package.json` file that has the `main` property set:

> cannot find module "./MyComponent"`

**Folder structure:**

```
src/
|- App.tsx
|- MyComponent/
|    |- MyComponent.tsx
|    |- package.json
|    |- ...
```

MyComponent.tsx:

```
export default class extends Component {
  ...
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-component",
  "version": "0.0.0",  
  "main": "MyComponent.tsx"
}
```

If I change `MyComponent.tsx` to `index.tsx`, it works, but I thought that the purpose of `main` in `package.json` was to do exactly what I'm trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `main` field only supports resolving modules with the `.js` extension and the `types` field (the TypeScript analog to `main`) supports `.d.ts` fields. The [TypeScript module resolution docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) only describe usages with those extensions.

The reason behind this is that these are fields intended for use with published packages. `.ts` (or `.tsx` in your case) files are development files intended to be transpiled into production-ready JavaScript (and helper metadata files). If a published package even included `.ts` files (instead of their resulting `.d.ts`, `.js`, and `.js.map` outputs), attempting to require those files would be very undesirable.

Your TypeScript is always transpiled into JS before it is executed. Support for streamlined includes of TypeScript files by the compiler assumes that these includes are also being transpiled before run-time.

As long as your `tsconfig.json` is configured to output the declaration (and source map) files:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    ...
```

You can point your `main` and `types` fields to the output files:

```
"main": "myComponent.js",
"types: "myComponent.d.ts",
```

And once those files are created, they will resolve correctly. Note this means if you're using any coding assistance it usually means you have to re-compile to get updated hints.

If you want the automatic code assist, the `index.tsx` might be a better route. If you really want to avoid continously editing multiple `index.tsx` files, you can just have them re-export the module:

```
export * from '/MyComponent';
```

EDIT: Include actual solution...

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! So, are you saying that there is no trivial way to do this in Typescript (or no way at all) and that your recommendation is to stick with an index.tsx file instead? I find that very annoying, as the library grows, to have many index.tsx files open in VS Code.

Comment: I updated my answer; I apologize I had to leave somewhat abruptly before. As a side note, I don't use VS Code very often, but some editors (WebStorm in my case) will display `MyComponent/index.tsx` or `OtherFolder/index.tsx` if both are open at the same time. There might be an extension for this for VS Code.

Comment: Great, thanks for this. I reverted to index, but I now understand why it didn't work. I'll try one more time!

Comment: I can't believe that after nearly 2.5 years, that this is still not possible.