# Would it make sense for the TypeScript compiler to look alongside "main" for definitions?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

This question concerns the way tsc does module resolution.  This process is very well defined [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

My question is specifically about the Node module resolution strategy.  I understand that tsc will search in `node_modules` folders moving up the filesystem.  As it searches each `node_modules` folder, it will look for a subdirectory named after the package.  Then, it will look for .ts, .tsx and .d.ts files within the *root* of that directory.  Failing to find the package's definitions, it will look for a "types" property in package.json.

Typically, when I create a Node.js package, my transpiled .js files are placed in a `dist` folder.  Because these files do not reside in the root of my package's folder, I am forced to set the "main" property in package.json to the primary .js output file and the "types" property to the primary .d.ts file.  Perhaps I am being lazy, but I don't know why I should have to specify both "main" and "types".  Requiring both seems unnecessary and just one more thing that can be forgotten.  Wouldn't it make sense that if "main" has a value of "dist/index.js" that tsc should attempt to see if "dist/index.ts", "dist/index.tsx" or "dist/index.d.ts" exist?  In other words, wouldn't it make sense to look alongside the "main" file for the definitions file?

In my searching, I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48159833/typescript-module-resolution-fails-despite-main-property-set-in-package-json) question, but the answer basically reiterates that this is not the way Node style module resolution works.  I am more interested to know whether this is a worthy improvement and if there is a technical reason why it shouldn't be done.

Example:

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My TS Library",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

If the resolution would look alongside the `main` file, the `types`  property would not be needed.