# Resolve Typescript file by using folder name

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm porting my code from ES6 to .TS / .TSX

Given a folder structure like this:

`Table/Tables.tsx`

Importing from another react component in ES6 I used to be able to just do this:

`import Table from '../Table'`

i.e. it would be smart enough to resolve the import by folder name. Now that I've switched to Typescript I have to import more verbosely (from another .tsx file);

`import Table from '../Table/Table'`

I've looked here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

I'm using Webpack with [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the same question, asked a bit differently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48159833/typescript-module-resolution-fails-despite-main-property-set-in-package-json)

The package.json modification didn't work for me, so I just changed my convention to naming  the component `Index.tsx` in each subfolder.

Answer (score 3):

Inside each folder you wan to import, have an index.ts file with all exports of that folder. Then you will be able to import individual components by only specifying folder path

`import {table} from ../table/`

Comment: ok that's helpful, I was trying to avoid having another file as I am following the one folder one ocmponent convention, so I could just rename my component to index.ts in this case.